# O que ocorre em 1...1 no PHP?

Tags: php

Na web deparei-me com o seguinte trecho de código:

```php
echo 1...1;
```

Resultando em `10.1`. Fiz o `var_dump` do mesmo e o retorno é:

```
string(4) "10.1"
```

Funciona com atribuição à variável:

```php
$x = 1...1;
echo $x; // 10.1
```

E para outros valores:

```php
echo 2...2; // 20.2
echo 1...1; // 10.2
echo 3...2; // 30.2
```

Eu sei que no PHP 5.6+ existe o operador `...` (*splat operator*), que extrai os valores de um *array* - semelhante ao `*` do Python - porém não parece ser o caso, até porquê, de acordo com o site [3V4L](https://3v4l.org/HXAvq), o resultado é o mesmo desde a versão 4.3.0, que nem existia esse operador.

Aparentemente só funciona com inteiros.

Seria alguma concatenação implícita de valores que o PHP faz?

Comment: Coitadinho do PHP.

Comment: Eu nunca deixo de me surpreender com PHP :)

Comment: Que tragédia, cada dia descubro uma nova.

Comment: Crendeuspai. Eu já falei mais de uma vez e repito: Se eu não fosse obrigado a trabalhar com PHP, já tinha abandonado faz tempo. Parece que o padrão das coisas com PHP é undefined behavior ou sintaxe confusa.

Comment: Quanto mimimi, a resposta já esclareceu :p

Answer (score 41, accepted):

De fato, o que ocorre é a concatenação de valores do tipo `float`. O PHP analisa `1.` como sendo `float(1.0)` e `.1` como sendo `float(0.1)`, desta forma, acontece a concatenação de `float(1.0) . float(0.1)`, porém, como `1.0` é inteiro, o PHP mantém apenas `1`.

```
1. . .1
|  |  |
|  |  +--- Analisado como float 0.1
|  +--- Operador de concatenação de string, faz o cast dos operandos para string
+--- Analisado como float 1.0, feito o cast para int
```

Ou seja, fazer:

```php
echo 1...1;
```

É o mesmo que:

```php
echo (1.).(.1);
```

Tanto que é possível acrescentar a parte decimal do primeiro valor:

```php
echo 5.32..7; // 5.320.7
```

Mas não é possível adicionar uma parte inteira ao segundo valor:

```php
echo 3..5.67; // Syntax error
```

Apenas se inserir devidamente os parenteses:

```php
echo 3..(5.67); // 35.67
```

Ou se inserir espaços entre os operadores:

```php
echo 3. . 5.67; // 35.67
```

Utilizando o espaço é possível definir ainda tanto a parte decimal do primeiro valor quanto a parte inteira do segundo:

```php
echo 3.14 . 1.41; // 3.141.41
```

#### Resumo da ópera

Executei uma série de [testes](http://ideone.com/1yIwXd) e o resultado está abaixo. Não incluí situações que gerariam erro de sintaxe.

```
1...1        = 10.1
2...2        = 20.2
10...10      = 100.1
(1.).(.1)    = 10.1
1. . .1      = 10.1
5.32..7      = 5.320.7
3..(5.67)    = 35.67
3. . 5.67    = 35.67
3.14 . 1.41  = 3.141.41
```

Conforme os testes no [3V4L](https://3v4l.org/sLrdE#v430), a saída é a mesma desde a versão 4.3.0:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Agora fez sentido. +1

Comment: Existe algum link, algum texto oficial, alguma coisa que diga o porque foi feito assim?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic acredito que não. A documentação do PHP peca muito nesses aspectos.

Comment: Gizuis. E eu achava que só o JS gostava de ser críptico. :-(

Comment: Eu tentnedo é que não é que "foi feito assim". O que acontece é que 'ficou assim", quando se toma algumas outras decisões - Nese caso, principalmente a de  usar o "." como operador de concatenar strings que faz casting automático para "str". 
Esses corner-cases estranhos derivados de regras que são bem sensatas quando usadas no contexto certo são comuns em todas as linguagens.