# O que ocorre na expressão "$a+++(++$a)"?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, operadores, sintaxe

Eu estava brincando com o PHP para ver se conseguia achar algo que soasse estranho com a sintaxe, me inspirando na pergunta [O que ocorre em 1...1 no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208629/o-que-ocorre-em-1-1-no-php/208636).

Eu acabei me deparando com o código:

```
$a = 0;

$a+++(++$a)
```

A "brincadeira" acima retornou `2`.

Porque retornou `2`? O que detalhadamente o PHP processou nessa sentença?

Teste no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/A5QRBK)

Comment: 1 + 1 = 2. Não?

Comment: @Francisco sim, mas o que ocorre na sintaxe?

Comment: `$a++` é a mesma coisa que `$a = $a + 1;` O `(++$a)` também funciona da mesma forma neste caso. Nisso você soma os dois e da 2.

Comment: Talvez algo igualmente interessante `$a++-(++$a);` = 2, se analisar a expressão, 1 - 1 = 2 (?)

Comment: No próprio manual tem uma ótima explicação
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.increment.php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A expressão que o PHP percebe será:

```
$a++ + (++$a)
```

Como qualquer expressão é analisada a partir da esquerda, ocorrerá:

1. Analisar-se-á a operação `$a++`, produzindo o valor atual de `$a` como resultado e posteriormente incrementando a variável. Isto é, retorna-se 0 e o valor de `$a` passa a ser 1;
2. Analisar-se-á a operação de adição `+`. Como é uma operação que exige dois operandos, será feita a adição de zero, o valor retornado no passo 1, e o resultado de `++$a`. Então, antes da adição, o segundo operando será analisado;
3. Analisar-se-á a operação `++$a`. O valor de `$a` será incrementado e o resultado será retornado. Como o valor atual de `$a` é 1, vide passo 1, será incrementado para 2 e retornado;
4. Assim, voltando ao passo 2, a operação de adição será analisada com os operandos 0 e 2, retornados nos passos 1 e 3 respectivamente;

A presença dos parenteses na expressão serve apenas para deixar a sintaxe válida, uma vez que, sem eles, `$a+++++$a`, o PHP não conseguiria aferir corretamente qual é a expressão, pois a expressão que perceberia seria algo como `$a + ++ ++$a`, resultando em erro de sintaxe ao tentar avaliar esse `++` sobrando na expressão. Tanto que os parenteses são desnecessários se utilizado devidamente espaços em branco, produzindo exatamente o mesmo resultado:

```
$a++ + ++$a
```

Tudo isso pode ser confirmado ao analisar o código com o VLD:

```
<?php

$a = 0;

echo $a+++(++$a);
```

Gerando os *opcodes*:

```
Finding entry points
Branch analysis from position: 0
Jump found. (Code = 62) Position 1 = -2
filename:       /in/PHp21
function name:  (null)
number of ops:  6
compiled vars:  !0 = $a
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  E >   ASSIGN                                                   !0, 0
   5     1        POST_INC                                         ~2      !0
         2        PRE_INC                                          $3      !0
         3        ADD                                              ~4      ~2, $3
         4        ECHO                                                     ~4
         5      > RETURN                                                   1
```

Onde leia-se:

1. Na linha 3, operação de atribuição é feita do valor 0 para o endereço `!0`;
2. Na Linha 5, ocorre:

   - Pós-incremento do valor em `!0`, armazenando o valor retornado em `~2`;

     - `!0` passa a ser 1, retornando o valor 0, armazenando em `~2`;
   - Pré-incremento do valor em `!0`, armazenando o valor em `$3`;

     - `!0` passa a ser 2, retornando o valor 2, armazenando em `$3`;
   - Adição entre os valores em `~2` e `$3`, 0 e 2 respectivamente, armazenando o resultado em `~4`;
   - O valor de `~4` é passado para a função `echo`;

Exatamente o mesmo processo descrito anteriormente.

---

Exatamente a mesma lógica ocorre ao analisar a expressão `$a++-(++$a)`, como [comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226847/o-que-ocorre-na-express%C3%A3o-aa/226868#comment464621_226847), mudando apenas a operação de adição para subtração, resultando, assim, 0-2 = -2.

Answer (score 8):

Se separarmos a sintaxe em cada expressão fica fácil entender:

```
$a = 0;
$b = $a++;
$c = ++$a;
var_dump($a, $b, $c, $b + $c);
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5iZt0T). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wnmnocku-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/ExpressionEvaluationOrder.php).

A expressão total é composta por uma adição de dois valores, ou seja o operador `+`  que está no meio é a o último cálculo realizado: é como se fizesse `($a++) + (++$a)`.

Antes ele precisa avaliar as expressões que estão dentro dos parênteses. Uma expressão pega o valor `$a` e **depois** faz um incremento, resultando em 0 já que `$a` valia 0, porém ao fina da expressão `$a` passa valer 1. Então `$b` vale 0. Note o uso do [operador de pós-incremento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80383/101).

Na outra expressão ele **antes** incrementa 1 no valor de `$a` que agora vale 1. E já que o operador de incremento não só dá um resultado, ele provoca efeito colateral na variável e muda seu valor também, então `$a` passa valer 2. Como desta vez o operador usado é de pré-incremento, o resultado final é o novo valor de `$a` e não mais o antigo como ocorreu na expressão anterior. Então `$c` vale 2, assim como `$a`.

Só que você não está mandando imprimir o valor de `$a`, está imprimindo o resultado da soma das duas expressões. No meu código joguei esses valores em variáveis `$b` e `$c` para ficar mais visível. E é a soma de ambos que está sendo impresso no seu código. Não é o valor de `$a` que coincidentemente tem o mesmo valor.

Há regras de sintaxe da linguagem para priorizar o que pegar no texto do código e tentar formar os operadores. Além disso a ordem de execução é determinada por tabela de precedência e associatividade.

O Victor Stafusa contestou a ordem que eu mostrei, mas [fiz um novo experimento](https://ideone.com/mCnLx3) e para estar certo e bater com a [tabela de precedência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47886/101). Somar 1 em ambos deixava ambíguo e dava margem para interpretação. Fiz com e sem parênteses e o resultado foi o mesmo. Separando as expressões e executando conforme a precedência da esquerda para a direita dá o mesmo resultado. Já fazendo da direita para a esquerda dá outro resultado, já que os parênteses não podem mudar a associatividade de um operador que está fora deles. Poderia mudar do que está dentro. Mas acho que isto é outro assunto, não vou me alongar.

Claro que os parênteses são necessários neste caso para evitar ambiguidade de sintaxe, mas nada afeta a ordem de execução.

Comment: Na verdade o `c` seria interpretado primeiro por causa dos parênteses.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Não neste caso, pois não há conflito entre as precedências dos operadores. A execução é exatamente esta que o bigown colocou (veja no [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PHp21/vld#output))

Comment: @VictorStafusa tem certeza? Ele ignora a associatividade da esquerda para a direita? Realmente fiquei na dúvida agora. Se estiver certo o resultado intermediário seria diferente: https://ideone.com/L4AnTG

Answer (score 4):

Estado inicial:

```
$a = 0;
$x = $a+++(++$a);
```

Quando a operação de pós-incremento de `$a++` é avaliada, `$a` ainda vale 0. Temos neste momento:

```
$x = 0 + (++$a);
$a = 1;
```

Ao avaliar a operação de pré-incremento de `++$a`, `$a` já está valendo 1. Temos então:

```
$x = 0 + 2; // $x = 2
$a = 2;
```

---

Note que se você inverter a expressão a resposta ainda será 2, mas os valores da expressão mudam:

```
$a = 0;
$x = ++$a+$a++;
```

Quando a operação de pré-incremento de `++$a` é avaliada, `$a` passa a valer 1. Temos neste momento:

```
$x = 1 + $a++;
$a = 1;
```

Quando a operação de pós-incremento de `$a++` é avaliada, `$a` ainda vale 1. Temos então:

```
$x = 1 + 1; // $x = 2
$a = 2;
```

---

Agora um exemplo com uma expressão maior. Porque `$a+++(++$a+$a+++(++$a))` é igual a 8?

Estado inicial:

```
$a = 0
$x = $a+++(++$a+$a+++(++$a));
```

Quando a primeira operação de pós-incremento de `$a++` é avaliada, `$a` ainda vale 0. Temos neste momento:

```
$x = 0 + (++$a+$a+++(++$a));
$a = 1;
```

Quando a próxima operação de pré-incremento de `++$a` é avaliada, `$a` já está valendo 1. Temos então:

```
$x = 0 + (2 + $a+++(++$a));
$a = 2;
```

Quando a próxima operação de pós-incremento de `$a++` é avaliada, `$a` ainda vale 2. Temos portanto:

```
$x = 0 + (2 + 2 + (++$a));
$a = 3;
```

Quando a próxima operação de pré-incremento de `++$a` é avaliada, `$a` já está valendo 3. Temos por fim:

```
$x = 0 + 2 + 2 + 4; // $x = 8
$a = 4;
```